# Node.js check if ftp credentials are valid

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

I'm using `jsftp` for ftp connection and I'm trying to write a code that checks if the provided ftp credentials are valid.

This is what I've made so far and it returns the error if the credentials are invalid, but if they are valid it doesn't execute the `else` condition

```
  var ftp = new JSFtp({
    "host": req.body.host,
    "port": req.body.port,
    "user": req.body.user, 
    "pass": req.body.pass
  });

  ftp.on('error', function(err){
    if(err) {
      return err;   
    }
    else {
      console.log('test');
      // Do something else
    }
  });
```

Comment: The else condition is just a comment. How can you tell it isn't being executed? (Hint: Provide a [mcve])

Comment: Updated my question. It should log "test" in the console, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
  var ftp = new JSFtp({
    "host": req.body.host,
    "port": req.body.port,
    "user": req.body.user, 
    "pass": req.body.pass
  });

  ftp.on('error', function(err){
    if(err) {
      return err;   
    }
  })

  ftp.on('data', function(data) {
     console.log('The provided ftp location is valid');
     // do stuff here...
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsftp#ftpauthusername-password-callback).

```
Ftp.auth(username, password, callback)
```

> Authenticates the user with the given username and password. If null
>   or empty values are passed for those, auth will use anonymous
>   credentials. callback will be called with the response text in case of
>   successful login or with an error as a first parameter, in normal Node
>   fashion.

Example:

```
ftp.auth(username, password, function(err, success){
   if(err) {
    // handle error conditon
   }else{
     // login success
   }


})
```

Comment: `username` and `password` should be the same as the ones from `req.body.user` and `req.body.pass` ?

Comment: @Valip yes give same username and password

Comment: I get the following error in the console if I provide a wrong `host`: `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`

Comment: Why you are providing wrong host.? What is your goal?

Comment: My goal is to be able to retrieve the files from a ftp location

Comment: Did you check documentation? There is an example

Comment: The code that you have posted above , you have used the "error" event and corresponding that you receive an err object . So the execution will only go inside the even catching code when an error occurs and in that case the "err" shall always be an object , hence no point of going inside else .